# Capistrano Deleting Paperclip Images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, capistrano

For some reason Capistrano deletes all the images in my database every time I cap all the images get removed from all the users. Typically what I have done is have to refill the databased with the same images that had been delete by capistrano. I've attached my deploy.rb file, can someone give me some insight.

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.3p429'
set :rvm_type, :user
set :user, ""
set :password, ""
set :domain, ""
set :applicationdir, ""

set :scm, :git
set :repository,  ""
set :git_enable_submodules, 1 # if you have vendored rails
set :branch, "release"
set :rails_env, 'production'

#set :git_shallow_clone, 1
set :scm_verbose, true

# roles (servers)
role :web, domain
role :app, domain
role :db,  domain, :primary => true
set :port, 22


# deploy config
set :deploy_to, applicationdir
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

# additional settings
default_run_options[:pty] = true  # Forgo errors when deploying from windows
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

#ssh_options[:keys] = %w(/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa)            # If you are using ssh_keysset :chmod755, "app config db lib public vendor script script/* public/disp*"set :use_sudo, false

# runtime dependencies
depend :remote, :gem, "bundler", ">=1.0.0.rc.2"


# tasks
namespace :deploy do
  task :start, :roles => :app do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  task :stop, :roles => :app do
    # Do nothing.
  end

  desc "Restart Application"
  task :restart, :roles => :app do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  desc "Symlink shared resources on each release"
  task :symlink_shared, :roles => :app do
    #run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
end



after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:symlink_shared'

namespace :bundler do
  desc "Symlink bundled gems on each release"
  task :symlink_bundled_gems, :roles => :app do
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/bundled_gems"
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/bundled_gems #{release_path}/vendor/bundle"
  end

  desc "Install for production"
  task :install, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{release_path} && bundle install --without development test"
  end

end

after 'deploy:update_code', 'bundler:symlink_bundled_gems'
after 'deploy:update_code', 'bundler:install'
```

Answer (score 6):

2 years later, same trouble...

Here's my fix. In your deploy.rb :

```
# Default value for linked_dirs is []
# set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('bin', 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('public/system')
```

This will store your images in yourapp/shared/system (instead of yourapp/current/system) and create symlinks on each deploy.

Source : https://github.com/capistrano/rails/issues/104#issuecomment-72766586

Comment: The directory that needs to be linked can apparently vary. For example, when using the ecommerce gem Spree (which uploads files via Paperclip), the images folder is `public/spree`.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely your `public/images` (or wherever Paperclip stores images) is not a shared symlink, and thus when Capistrano links a new release, the images are not copied.

There's documentation about this [right in the Paperclip README](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#understanding-storage) file, covering how not to fall into this trap.

Comment: Ok... but how do you fix it? I have the exact same problem but I have no idea how to fix it.